# How to track when song finished playing in AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, nsnotificationcenter

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 where I'm able to play songs through AVPlayer. My requirement is to track the point once the song finish playing and update the play button image accordingly. For that I have used a NSNotification instance. for some reason it throws an error saying

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Project.ViewController finishedPlaying:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fda8e928170'".

What am I missing here ?? my code as bellow.

```
 @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if newRowSelected == true{
        if(isNewPathSelected){
            print("player")
            let url:URL = savePath!
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
            player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
            let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
            playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50) // actually this player layer is not visible
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            isNewPathSelected = false
        }

        if player?.rate == 0 // this means if its not playing
        {
            print("Playing")
            player!.play()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            trackTime()

            if playerItem != nil {
                print("playerItem")
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("finishedPlaying:")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

            }

        } else {
            player!.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
    }else{
        showAlert()
    }

}

func finishedPlaying(myNotification:NSNotification) {
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play_button"), for: UIControlState.normal)

    let stopedPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = myNotification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    stopedPlayerItem.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}
```

Comment: are you implemented the `finishedPlaying` method in your class

Comment: yes i am its bellow the main code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your notification oberserver from

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("finishedPlaying:")), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
```

into swift3 syntax

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishedPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
```

and call the method as

```
@objc func finishedPlaying( _ myNotification:NSNotification) {

}
```

Comment: I cant do like that since im using "myNotification" in the code

Comment: Also worsk with Swift 4+

Comment: I had added `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver...` and declared @objc in my Swift class but the @objc is never called.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your code for NSNotificationCenter as below

```
 let url:URL = savePath!
 playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
 player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
 let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
 playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50) 
             // actually this player layer is not visible
 self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)


func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        print("Video Finished")
  }
```

Comment: means you want to whole answer with your context ?

Comment: I had added `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver...` and declared @objc in my Swift class but the @objc is never called.

Answer (score 0):

```
var streamPlayer = AVPlayer()

func playStreamAudio( for audioUrl:String)
    {
        guard streamPlayer.timeControlStatus != .playing else {
            streamPlayer.pause()
            return
        }
        let url = audioUrl //"http://192.168.71.11:7891/rec.wav"
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string:url)!)
        streamPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        streamPlayer.rate = 1.0;
        streamPlayer.volume = 1.0
        streamPlayer.play()
    }
```